# Find functions explicitly defined in a module (python)

Tags: python, introspection

Ok I know you can use the dir() method to list everything in a module, but is there any way to see only the functions that are defined in that module?  For example, assume my module looks like this:

```
from datetime import date, datetime

def test():
    return "This is a real method"
```

Even if i use inspect() to filter out the builtins, I'm still left with anything that was imported.  E.g I'll see:

['date', 'datetime', 'test']

Is there any way to exclude imports?  Or another way to find out what's defined in a module?

Comment: What's wrong with reading the source?

Comment: In Python, "method" is generally only used to refer to functions that are attributes of a class.  Your `test()` is better referred to as a "function".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting a list of locally-defined functions in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18451541/getting-a-list-of-locally-defined-functions-in-python)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
import sys, inspect

def is_mod_function(mod, func):
    return inspect.isfunction(func) and inspect.getmodule(func) == mod

def list_functions(mod):
    return [func.__name__ for func in mod.__dict__.itervalues() 
            if is_mod_function(mod, func)]


print 'functions in current module:\n', list_functions(sys.modules[__name__])
print 'functions in inspect module:\n', list_functions(inspect)
```

EDIT: Changed variable names from 'meth' to 'func' to avoid confusion (we're dealing with functions, not methods, here).

Comment: @ars Couldn't you just replace your functions with `[f[1] for f in inspect.getmembers(mod) if inspect.isfunction(f[1])]` and get the same results?

Comment: Nevermind, that would include imported functions, still need the `getmodule(func) == mod` for it to work, but still one-ish liner.

Comment: Is there a way to make this work with decorated functions?

Answer (score 5):

How about the following:

```
grep ^def my_module.py
```

Comment: It's a quick and dirty solution that works.  It may not be the best solution for your problem but I wouldn't know because I don't know what problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 2):

You can check `__module__` attribute of the function in question. I say "function" because a method belongs to a class usually ;-).

BTW, a class actually also has `__module__` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Every class in python has a `__module__` attribute. You can use its value to perform filtering. Take a look at [example 6.14 in dive into python](http://diveintopython.net/file_handling/more_on_modules.html)

Comment: Functions have the `__module__` attribute too.

Answer (score 0):

the python [inspect](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/inspect.html) module is probably what you're looking for here.

```
import inspect
if inspect.ismethod(methodInQuestion):
    pass # It's a method
```

Comment: Looks like it would work in combination with Stefano's answer. You can see what's a method and what's imported.

Comment: I'm commenting on this post because my rep is under 50. Functions have __module__ attribute too.

Answer (score 0):

```
import inspect, sys

def get_module_func(module):
    is_function_in_module = lambda obj: inspect.isfunction(obj) and inspect.getmodule(obj) == module
    return inspect.getmembers(module, is_function_in_module)

get_module_func(sys.modules[__name__])
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).