# Is it possible to list all functions in a module?

Tags: python, python-module

I defined a .py file in this format:

#### foo.py

```
def foo1(): pass
def foo2(): pass
def foo3(): pass
```

I import it from another file:

#### main.py

```
from foo import * 
# or
import foo
```

Is it possible list all functions name, e.g. `["foo1", "foo2", "foo3"]`?

---

Thanks for your help, I made a class for what I want, pls comment if you have suggestion

```
class GetFuncViaStr(object):
    def __init__(self):
        d = {}
        import foo
        for y in [getattr(foo, x) for x in dir(foo)]:
            if callable(y):
               d[y.__name__] = y
    def __getattr__(self, val) :
        if not val in self.d :
           raise NotImplementedError
        else:
           return d[val]
```

Comment: This is a terrible idea. Use a decorator to enumerate the functions you care about.

Comment: Thanks Ignacio, but to put a @push_to_list on each function may cause a lot of replacement work in my case, can you show me why it is a bad idea?

Comment: You may not want all the functions in the module to be available for use.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The cleanest way to do these things is to use the inspect module. It has a `getmembers` function that takes a predicate as the second argument. You can use `isfunction` as the predicate.

```
 import inspect

 all_functions = inspect.getmembers(module, inspect.isfunction)
```

Now, `all_functions` will be a list of tuples where the first element is the name of the function and the second element is the function itself.

Comment: I have no python env right now to test, is the func item in list do not need an "import" for invoking anymore just all_functions[0][1](para)?

Comment: @user478514  You have to import it initially to call `getmembers` on it but after that, the second element of each tuple is a function with it's globals bound to the globals of the module that it is defined in. No further reference need be made to that module.

Comment: How to list all functions in the current file when you don't know module name?

Comment: Wow, really cool.  Much better than using `dir()`, since that just provides the module attributes (the behaviour of which can be overriden by defining [`__getattribute__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) in the module).

Comment: To only include functions that have been defined in that module (not imported), see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106840/find-functions-explicitly-defined-in-a-module-python

Comment: To inspect the current module, use `sys.modules[__name__]` instead of `module`.

Comment: Hi how can I get the order of definition?

Answer (score 10):

you can use dir to explore a namespace.

```
import foo
print dir(foo)
```

Example: loading your foo in shell

```
>>> import foo
>>> dir(foo)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'foo1', 'foo2', 'foo3']
>>> 
>>> getattr(foo, 'foo1')
<function foo1 at 0x100430410>
>>> k = getattr(foo, 'foo1')
>>> k.__name__
'foo1'
>>> callable(k)
True
>>>
```

You can use getattr to get the associated attribute in foo and find out if it callable.

Check the documentation : http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-dir-function

and if you do - "from foo import *" then the names are included in the namespace where you call this.

```
>>> from foo import *
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'atexit', 'foo1', 'foo2', 'foo3']
>>>
```

The following brief on introspection in python might help you :

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-pyint.html

Comment: Take a look at inspect also: http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html

Answer (score 8):

Like 
[aaronasterling said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4040709/247696), you can use the [getmembers](http://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmembers) functions from the `inspect` module to do this.

```
import inspect

name_func_tuples = inspect.getmembers(module, inspect.isfunction)
functions = dict(name_func_tuples)
```

However, this **will include functions that have been defined elsewhere**, but imported into that module's namespace.

If you want to get only the functions that have been defined in that module, use this snippet:

```
name_func_tuples = inspect.getmembers(module, inspect.isfunction)
name_func_tuples = [t for t in name_func_tuples if inspect.getmodule(t[1]) == module]
functions = dict(name_func_tuples)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using inspect module like below for exmaple if module --> temp.py

```
In [26]: import inspect

In [27]: import temp

In [28]: l1 = [x.__name__ for x in temp.__dict__.values() if inspect.isfunction(x)]

In [29]: print l1
['foo', 'coo']
```

Answer (score 2):

For a wild import

```
from foo import * 
print dir()
```

you can use `dir()` without a parameter to show objects in the current module's namespace. This will most probably include more than just the content of `foo`.

In case of an absolute import (which you should prefer by the way) you can pass the module to `dir()`:

```
import foo
print dir(foo)
```

Also check the [documentation of `dir`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#dir). As you only wanted functions, you might want to think about using [`inspect.isfunction`](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.isfunction). Hope you don't use that list for non-debugging purposes.

Comment: thanks,is it means I may have to filter the result of dir() in order to get all functions?

Comment: @user478514: Just edited to answer that ;) You can use `inspect.isfunction`.

Answer (score 2):

if wanting to list functions of the current module (i.e., not an imported one), you could also do something like this:

```
import sys
def func1(): pass
def func2(): pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print dir(sys.modules[__name__])
```