# How can A.f defined in module A get list of function defined in B if A.f was called from B

Tags: python, introspection

Let's say I have `B.py`

```
import A

def F():
    pass

def G():
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    A.f()
```

And when I run it I would like `A.f` to output list of functions defined in `B.py` like this

```
./B.py
['F', 'G']
```

The question is what should I write in `A.py`?

```
def f():
    ???
```

It seems to be possible because `doctest` does something like this.

**Update** Thank you for your responses, but I forgot to mention one more restriction: I would not like to do `import B` in `A.py`.

Let me try to explain why: `A.py` is a library for runing MapReduce jobs. You just import `A` and run some `A.f` at the vary end of your script. Then `A.f` analizes what functions you defined and executes them on server. So `A.f` can not import every module it was called from.

Or can it? Can function know where it was called from?

**Update**

```
def f():
    module = sys.modules['__main__']
    functions = inspect.getmembers(module, inspect.isfunction)
    ...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find functions explicitly defined in a module (python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106840/find-functions-explicitly-defined-in-a-module-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def f():
    import B
    import inspect

    functions=inspect.getmembers(B,inspect.isfunction)
```

http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmembers

**EDIT**

I haven't tried it, but it seems like you could pass the module as an argument to f and use that.

```
def f(mod):
    import inspect
    functions=inspect.getmembers(mod,inspect.isfunction)
    return functions
```

Then, from B, you could do something like:

```
import sys
import A
myfuncs=A.f(sys.modules[__name__])
```

Comment: @alexanderkuk I've posted an idea that *might* work for you, though I don't have the time to test it.

Comment: @tapan  Thanks.  I'll remove the disclaimer.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually pretty easy to do using [the `dir()` function](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-dir-function):

```
import B

def f():
    print(dir(B))
```

Which gives:

```
['A', 'F', 'G', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__']
```

As you can see, this does include the hidden values that exist in the module that you normally don't see. If you want to be more specific about the things you want, check out [the `inspect` module](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html).

Comment: You can't do circular imports.

Comment: @NiklasB. You can - try running this. It works. I'm not saying it's a great practice, but it does work.

Comment: Really? I have to check, last time I needed something like this it wasn't possible. Disregard my comment if it is, of course.

Comment: Indeed. I stand corrected. Maybe you should do `filter(callable, dir(B))`, though.

Comment: @NiklasB. You can run into problems with circular imports, but it won't produce errors in all cases.

Comment: Yeah, last time it would work, but `B` would have no members inside `A`. Obviously this has changed since.