# Getting a list of locally-defined functions in python

Tags: python, function

If I have a script like this:

```
import sys

def square(x):
    return x*x

def cube(x):
    return x**3
```

How can I return a list of all the functions defined locally in the program `['square', 'cube']`, and not the ones imported.

They are included when I try `dir()` but so are all the variables and other imported modules. I don't know what to put into `dir` to refer to the locally executing file.

Comment: try `locals()`, but I'm not sure how helpful that would be

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
l = []
for key, value in locals().items():
    if callable(value) and value.__module__ == __name__:
        l.append(key)
print l
```

So a file with the content:

```
from os.path import join

def square(x):
    return x*x

def cube(x):
    return x**3

l = []
for key, value in locals().items():
    if callable(value) and value.__module__ == __name__:
        l.append(key)
print l
```

Prints:

```
['square', 'cube']
```

Local scopes also work:

```
def square(x):
    return x*x

def encapsulated():
    from os.path import join

    def cube(x):
        return x**3

    l = []
    for key, value in locals().items():
        if callable(value) and value.__module__ == __name__:
            l.append(key)
    print l

encapsulated()
```

Prints out only:

```
['cube']
```

Comment: Even as a one_liner: `functions = [name for (name, thing) in locals().items() if callable(thing])`

Comment: I like this solution because it doesn't rely on importing other modules, but when I try this in my actual script, it includes `'value'` as an entry in `l` for some reason that I can't figure out... "Value" doesn't appear elsewhere in the script.

Comment: @beroe are you doing it twice maybe?

Comment: **1.** If I have the answer of alecxe in the program along with this one, and it prints "value" from his assignment, so I guess it is working but affected by other calls to `inspect()`? **2** The one-liner by @9000 shows my imported functions too, perhaps because it omits `val.__module__ == __name__` (There is also a typo with your closing brackets). This works: `functions = [name for (name, thing) in locals().items() if (callable(thing) and thing.__module__ == __name__)]`

Comment: Oh... `key` and `value` are in `locals`, and `value` is assigned the values of all the other local variables in sequence. On Python 3, this modifies the global variable dict while iterating over it, producing undefined behavior. On Python 2, it might still produce really weird results. It's probably best to encapsulate this in a function and use `globals`.

Comment: Using python 3.7, list comprehensions work as expected, however when appending results to a list, I get `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`. Presumably to get around this, `locals()` needs to be updated each iteration? Or as @user2357112supportsMonica pointed out, using `globals()` inside a function works as expected.

Answer (score 9):

Use [inspect](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) module:

```
def is_function_local(object):
    return isinstance(object, types.FunctionType) and object.__module__ == __name__

import sys
print inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[__name__], predicate=is_function_local)
```

Example:

```
import inspect
import types
from os.path import join

def square(x):
    return x*x

def cube(x):
    return x**3

def is_local(object):
    return isinstance(object, types.FunctionType) and object.__module__ == __name__

import sys
print [name for name, value in inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[__name__], predicate=is_local)]
```

prints:

```
['cube', 'is_local', 'square']
```

See: no `join` function imported from `os.path`.

`is_local` is here, since it's a function is the current module. You can move it to another module or exclude it manually, or define a `lambda` instead (as @BartoszKP suggested).

Comment: Gives [('cube', <function cube at 0x0294AC70>), ('join', <function join at 0x025A58B0>), ('square', <function square at 0x028BBAB0>)] when `from os.path import join` added

Comment: @Marcin: That example only appears to exclude imported functions because built-in functions don't count for `inspect.isfunction`. The new version works, though.

Comment: I modified `is_local` to exclude itself, and this works. Thanks.  `return isinstance(object, types.FunctionType) and object.__module__ == __name__ and object.__name__ !='is_local'`

Answer (score 6):

Using Python 3.9.7,
When trying the most upvoted answer:

```
l = []
for key, value in locals().items():
    if callable(value) and value.__module__ == __name__:
        l.append(key)
print(l)
```

I got the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Name\Path\filename.py", line X, in 
**for key, value in locals().items():
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration**

Because the answer: locals() prints this:

```
'test_01': <function test_01 at 0x00000285B0F2F5E0>
'test_02': <function test_02 at 0x00000285B0F2FA60>
```

I just check if we get the string: "function" in the dictionary.

I used the following code to achieve my needs. Hope maybe this can help.

```
l = []
copy_dict = dict(locals())
for key, value in copy_dict.items():
    if "function" in str(value):
        l.append(key)
print(l)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import sys
import inspect
from os.path import join

def square(x):
    return x*x

def cube(x):
    return x**3

print inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[__name__], \
      predicate = lambda f: inspect.isfunction(f) and f.__module__ == __name__)
```

Prints:

`[('cube', <function cube at 0x027BAC70>), ('square', <function square at 0x0272BAB0>)]`