# how to find user defined functions in python script

Tags: function, python-2.7, user-defined-functions, built-in

A python program has builtin functions and user defined functions in it.
I wish to list out all the user defined functions in that program.
Could any one suggest me the way to how to do it?

example:

```
class sample():

     def __init__(self):
         .....some code....
     def func1():
         ....some operation...
     def func2():
         ...some operation..
```

I need output like this:

```
func1

func2
```

Comment: Which program? Do you have any sample code?

Comment: any python code which has number of user defined functions.

Comment: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106840/find-functions-explicitly-defined-in-a-module-python) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18451541/getting-a-list-of-locally-defined-functions-in-python) may be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn’t strictly true. The dir() function “attempts to produce the most relevant, rather than complete, information”. 
Source:

[How do I get list of methods in a Python class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911281/how-do-i-get-list-of-methods-in-a-python-class)

[Is it possible to list all functions in a module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040620/is-it-possible-to-list-all-functions-in-a-module)

Answer (score 0):

A cheap trick in Python 3.x would be this:

```
sample = Sample()
[i for i in dir(sample) if not i.startswith("__")]
```

which returns non-magic functions that start with double underscores.

```
['func1', 'func2']
```