# Make a Python script interact with a running Python script

Tags: python, interaction

I have two Python scripts, a.py and b.py. A.py is running and is not writable and I would like to have b.py being able to retrieve data from it, like a list of used variables and their values, functions, class... I am finding nothing on the Internet so is this possible ?
Thanks.

Example a.py

```py
def numberOne(var):
    var1 = input('Enter a value : ')

class testClass():
    def __init__(self, value)
        self.var2 = value

var3 = 12345
```

Example b.py output

```
Found class : 
-- testClass

Found functions :
-- numberOne

Found vars :
-- var3 : 12345
```

Comment: You need to provide an example for a.py and b.py file for better response

Comment: Sure it is. But we need more information on the contents of `a.by` and `b.py` and how you want to hook them up

Comment: It's called inter-process communication but it would be better if you provide more infomration about your scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be what you want but
You could try writing the data you need from `a.py` to `c.py` while `a.py` is running.

```
f = open('text.txt', 'w')
f.write(what_you_want_to_write)
```

And then work with it in `b.py`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, not quite what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There should be an IPC (inter-process communication) between a.py and b.py.

In module a.py, you should have some line of codes getting all function, variable in a.py, then transmit these data to b.py via IPC.
Please refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18451541/getting-a-list-of-locally-defined-functions-in-python) for getting the function list in a module.

Comment: Hey, thanks, I just modified the post because I figured out it's not really what I wanted. A.py is actually not writable.