# How to programmatically ensure that a function includes a return statement?

Tags: python, function

How can I validate that a function includes a `return` keyword? I frequently forget the return line, so I am worried that the users of my package will too when they provide a function-based input.

```py
def appler():
    a = "apple"
    # `return` is missing

def bananer():
    b = "banana"
    return b
```

I could parse the actual code string of the function for a final line that includes `"return"` but that isn't very robust (it could be triggered by comments).

```py
def validate_funk(funk):
    if condition_to_check_that_it_contains_rtrn:
        pass
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Yikes - The function you provided not contain a `return` statement:\n\n{funk}")
```

```py
>>> validate_funk(appler)
#triggers ValueError

>>> validate_funk(bananer)
# passes
```

EDIT: ideally without running the function.

Comment: This becomes a non-issue when you write unit tests for your code/functions

Comment: Could some of these help you avoid making mistakes? https://blog.codacy.com/which-python-static-analysis-tools-should-i-use/

Comment: funk is a user-provided argument.

Comment: BTW, both of the functions in the question are simple enough that they should probably skip the local variable; just: `def appler(): return "apple"`

Answer (score 4):

What you actually care about is probably not the return statement itself, but that the function returns *something* of a certain type. This you can most easily accomplish by using [type hints (PEP 484)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/):

```
def appler() -> str:
    a = "apple"
    # `return` is missing

def bananer() -> str:
    b = "banana"
    return b
```

Now, running a [static analysis tool](https://github.com/analysis-tools-dev/static-analysis#python) like mypy or Pyre (or many others): will emit a warning about a wrong return type in function `appler` (expected `str`, got `NoneType`).

Look for sabik's answer for a more general answer. Writing (unit) tests is another good practice that catches many more issues and - if done well - is an invest in code maintainability.

Answer (score 3):

A function without return statement returns `None` by default.

```
>>> def abc():
    pass
>>> print(abc())
None
>>>
```

You can add a check using this:

```
def validate_func(function):
    if function() == None:
        raise ValueError("Yikes - Does not contain a `return` statement")
```

There are few cons though.

1. You have to execute the function
2. It wont work if you are `return`ing `None` in a function

Not much practical but yea, that is one way. You can also get [a list of local functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18451587/8321664) or [a list of methods in a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911281/how-do-i-get-list-of-methods-in-a-python-class) and loop through them without having to check each function individually.

Comment: most of these functions should not return `None` so this is a good step in the right direction

Comment: yeah my `fn_train` trains a neural network and needs a lot of crazy input so that is a no go.

Answer (score 2):

For the question as asked, the `ast` module will let you check that.

However, it doesn't seem very useful just by itself - as others have pointed out, a function without a `return` is valid (it returns `None`), and just because a function does have a `return` doesn't mean that it returns the correct value, or even any value (the `return` could be in an `if` statement).

There are a couple of standard ways of dealing with this:

- Unit tests - separate code that calls your function with various combinations of inputs (possibly just one, possibly hundreds) and checks that the answers match the ones you calculated manually, or otherwise satisfy requirements.
- A more general implementation of the idea of checking for a `return` statement is "lint", in the case of Python `pylint`; that looks through your code and checks for various patterns that look like they could be mistakes. A side benefit is that it already exists and it checks dozens of common patterns.
- Another, different more general implementation is the `mypy` type checker; that not only checks that there's a `return` statement, but also that it returns the correct type, as annotated in the header of the function.

Typically, these would be used together with a "gated trunk" development process; manual changes to the `main` version are forbidden, and only changes which pass the tests, lint and/or mypy are accepted into the `main` version.

Comment: this is just meant to catch the 'doh forgot to return' when a user provides a function. cool,  looking at these now. upvoted. if you edit w an example i will accept.

Comment: If you're in any case calling the function provided by the user, you can check for a `None` return value at that point, or otherwise check that the returned value is valid (for instance, if it's a percentage it should be a number between 0 and 100). That will catch a bunch of other errors as well; after all, you don't care how the function is implemented, as long as it returns a usable value...

Comment: For example, the user could provide a function implemented as a `lambda`, which doesn't need the `return` keyword to return a value.

Comment: i see it here, but not sure how to isolate the method to call it or if that's possible https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/error_code_list.html?highlight=return#check-that-function-returns-a-value-return

Comment: That depends on the wider context. If your code is handed a function by the user, which you need to call, the most straightforward way is to check the return value after you've called it and give an error if it's not acceptable (eg. if it's `None` and that's not valid). If you want to check your own code, then you can run pylint or mypy over the whole code base and check that it doesn't report anything suspicious in any of the methods. If the code belongs to a group or a team, setting up a gated trunk with automated tests, pylint and/or mypy may be the way to go.

Comment: these are provided by the user and one of them trains a neural network, so i don't want to call them. they also include arguments which are filled in by my program downstream.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, simply calling the function is not enough: a `return` statement might only be present in a conditional, and thus, specific input would need to be passed in order to execute the `return` statement. That, too, is not a good indicator of the presence of a `return`, since it could `return` `None`, causing greater ambiguity. Instead, the `inspect` and `ast` module can be used:

Test functions:

```
def appler():
   a = "apple"
   # `return` is missing

def bananer():
   b = "banana"
   return b

def deeper_test(val, val1):
  if val and val1:
     if val+val1 == 10:
        return 

def gen_func(v):
   for i in v:
      if isinstance(i, list):
         yield from gen_func(i)
      else:
         yield i
```

---

`inspect.getsource` returns the entire source of the function as a string, which can then be passed to `ast.parse`. From there, the syntax tree can be recursively traversed, searching for the presence of a `return` statement:

```
import inspect, ast
fs = [appler, bananer, deeper_test, gen_func]
def has_return(f_obj):
   return isinstance(f_obj, ast.Return) or \
          any(has_return(i) for i in getattr(f_obj, 'body', []))

result = {i.__name__:has_return(ast.parse(inspect.getsource(i))) for i in fs}
```

Output:

```
{'appler': False, 'bananer': True, 'deeper_test': True, 'gen_func': False}
```

With a defined `validate_funk`:

```
def validate_funk(f):
   if not has_return(ast.parse(inspect.getsource(f))):
      raise ValueError(f"function '{f.__name__}' does not contain a `return` statement")
   return True
```

Notes:

1. This solution does not require the test functions to be called.
2. The solution must be run in a file. If it is run in the shell, an `OSError` will be raised. For the file, see [this](https://gist.github.com/Ajax12345/ae8466e7739a271819f10c91dbabc188) Github Gist.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify return checking with a decorator:

```py
def ensure_return(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        res = func(*args, **kwargs)
        if res is None:
            raise ValueError(f'{func} did not return a value')
        return res
    return wrapper

@ensure_return
def appler():
    a = "apple"
    # `return` is missing

@ensure_return
def bananer():
    b = "banana"
    return b
```

then:

```py
>>> appler()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in wrapper
ValueError: <function appler at 0x7f99d1a01160> did not return a value
>>> bananer()
'banana'
```