# How do I list all functions for a Python module ignoring functions the module imports?

Tags: python, import, module, python-import

I have a Python module 'something.py' and I'd like to get a list of all of the functions I've written in this file. I've followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139180/how-to-list-all-functions-in-a-python-module) SO post explaining the standard ways of doing this.

The trouble is I have import functions in something.py, so when trying to list my functions I also list the imported functions I don't care about. How can I get a list of the functions that I wrote in something.py?

Comment: Are you sure the answers in your [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139180/how-to-list-all-functions-in-a-python-module)  don't work?  For instance in the comments of the answer by adnan we see that  `from inspect import getmembers, isfunction; import something; functions_list = getmembers(something, isfunction)` provides a list only of functions in something module (i.e. functions of imports not included).

Comment: Unfortunately not, and I was surprised by this too. It works as expected when I comment my imports out but otherwise it fails. I suspect the problem is that I'm importing everything in my project's package which is probably causing it to behave differently than if I was just trying to import something from the standard library.

Comment: @Visipi--that's surprising since it works in my simple test program which 1) imports a module something and 2) something.py module imports something_else plus the math library.

Comment: Ah, thank you for sanity testing. Above and beyond. I'm quite sure now the problem is me. Probably something weird in my __init__ file. I'll consider that answered but I'm not sure how to give you points for a comment.

Comment: @Visipi--actually in this case I think stackoverflow (SO) considers it an unsuitable question since the problem can't be reproduced (i.e. thus any answer can't be used by others).  In which case, I think SO suggest removing the question, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I'll check. Thanks for your help @DarrylG!

Comment: @DarrylG In my test, that solution does not do what the OP wants. My `something` modules has this import: `from textwrap import dedent`. And the return from `getmembers()` includes `dedent`.

Comment: @FMc--you're right.  If something module has: `import something_else` (where something_else) is some other module then it does not show in the list of functions.  But, if you use from something_else import foo`, then foo does show in the list of functions.

Comment: @FMc--here's an old version of the question from 11 years ago--[Find functions explicitly defined in a module
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106840/find-functions-explicitly-defined-in-a-module-python) which worked once I updated the code to Python 3 (i.e. changed `itervalues` to `values`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updating functions from [this answer--Find functions explicitly defined in a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106840/find-functions-explicitly-defined-in-a-module-python) from Python 2 to 3 (i.e. replace itervalues() with values():

```
def is_mod_function(mod, func):
    ' checks that func is a function defined in module mod '
    return inspect.isfunction(func) and inspect.getmodule(func) == mod


def list_functions(mod):
    ' list of functions defined in module mod '
    return [func.__name__ for func in mod.__dict__.values() 
            if is_mod_function(mod, func)]
```

**Usage**

```
print(list_functions(something))  # Output: ['a1', 'b1']
```

File main.py (Main module)

```
import inspect
import something  # project module

def is_mod_function(mod, func):
    return inspect.isfunction(func) and inspect.getmodule(func) == mod


def list_functions(mod):
    return [func.__name__ for func in mod.__dict__.values() 
            if is_mod_function(mod, func)]

def list_functions1(mod):
    return [func.__name__ for func in mod.__dict__.itervalues() 
            if is_mod_function(mod, func)]


# Get list of functions defined only in module something
print(list_functions(something))
```

File something.py (something module)

```
from textwrap import dedent
from math import sin, cos
import numpy as np

def a1():
  pass

def b1():
  pass
```

**Output**

```
['a1', 'b1']  # shows only the functions defined in something.py
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import <modulename>
dir(modulename)
```

**2nd line of code will give the list of functions present in the module**

*Eg:*

```
import math
dir(math)
['__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'acos', 'acosh', 'asin', 'asinh', 'atan', 'atan2', 'atanh', 'ceil', 'copysign', 'cos', 'cosh', 'degrees', 'e', 'erf', 'erfc', 'exp', 'expm1', 'fabs', 'factorial', 'floor', 'fmod', 'frexp', 'fsum', 'gamma', 'hypot', 'isinf', 'isnan', 'ldexp', 'lgamma', 'log', 'log10', 'log1p', 'modf', 'pi', 'pow', 'radians', 'sin', 'sinh', 'sqrt', 'tan', 'tanh', 'trunc']
```

Comment: Yes, but dir() also lists every imported function in that file For example, suppose I have numpy imported into something.py. When I print dir(something), I'm not interested in seeing things from numpy.

Answer (score 2):

The `getmembers()` function includes imported functions, so you need more. One idea is to check the name of the module of the function.

```
from inspect import getmembers, isfunction
import something
import sys

mod = something

funcs = [
    f
    for _, f in getmembers(mod, isfunction)
    if f.__module__ == mod.__name__
]

for f in funcs:
    print(f)
```

Or you could do the filtering with this conditional instead:

```
if sys.modules[f.__module__] is mod
```

Either way, the output is:

```
<function bar at 0x107fb05f0>
<function foo at 0x107f840e0>
```

My `something` module has this:

```
import sys
from textwrap import dedent

fubb = 1

def foo():
    pass

def bar():
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dir(yourModule) to return a list of attributes: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir

Comment: But dir(yourModule) also lists the functions I imported in 'yourModule.' I'm only interested in listing the functions I wrote.

Comment: yes you're right, sorry about  that. I'm not sure if thats possible.. Have you figured it out already ?